# what causing meteor array of non-Cursor (DDP in meteor)

Tags: meteor, cursor, aggregation

just a quick question.

i have an example of publication using aggregation.

```
Meteor.publish('tags', function(tag){
    var sub = this;
    var pipeline = [
        {$project: {tags:1, author: 1, title:1, permalink:1 }},
        {$unwind:"$tags"},
        {$match: {"tags": tag}}];
    var results = Posts.aggregate(pipeline);
    var arrayLength = results.length;
    for(var i=0; i < arrayLength; i++){
          var tags = results[i];
          sub.added('posts', Math.random(), tags);
    }
    sub.ready();
});
```

why do i need to have an additional loop to store a data in the collection posts.

```
for(var i=0; i < arrayLength; i++){
   var tags = results[i];
   sub.added('posts', Math.random(), tags);
}
sub.ready();
```

if i return the result without including the loop for sub.added i will get the array of non-Cursor error on my client namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case ,

this code

```
sub.added('posts', Math.random(), tags);
```

we just say for DDP is to document it with `id = Math.random()` with `fields = tags` was added into posts collection. ddp is used to bond the client and server and it should transfer to the client when we subscribe (client apps).

An illustration of the meteor platform:
[image]

ddp is already a default package once meteor app is create.